# How to Notify single property change or modified in TrulyObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.android

How to invoke PropertyChanged when `IsLoaded` value changed.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; 
public bool IsLoaded { get; private set; }

public TrulyObservableCollection<Model> Alldata{ get; } = new TrulyObservableCollection<Model>();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just raise the event in the property setter. Did you mean something other?

Answer (score 2):

To invoke `PropertyChanged` just call `OnPropertyChanged` in the setter of your property

```
bool _isLoaded;

public bool IsLoaded
{
    get { return _isLoaded; }
    set
    {
        _isLoaded = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsLoaded));
    }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged (string name)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs (name));
}
```